# For two random variable with $E[|X_2|^2]>E[|X_1|^2]$ is it mean $|X_1|^2>|X_2|^2$

Tags: random-variables, variance

for $i\in\{1,2\}$, let $X_i$ Gaussian  random variable with mean zero
a and variance 1/2. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Let $E[|X_1|^2]=\delta_1$ and $E[|X_2|^2]=\delta_2$, where $\delta_2>\delta_1$.

Does this mean

$$|X_2|^2>|X_1|^2$$

always hold or not?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: Hi I am sorry I add all the problem.

Comment: Monir, the expression $E[ |X_1|^2]$ is the average value of $X_1$ squared.  If you wrote $X_1>1$ then sometimes it would be true, and sometimes it would be false.   $X_1$ is random.

Comment: So in general this is not true for independent positive e random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I case $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also independent the inequality $|X_2|^{2} >|X_1|^{2}$ cannot hold. Just use the fact that the joint density is positive at all points of the plane.

Comment: can you add more information please?

Comment: So for two positive independent random variables $|X_1|^2$ and $|X_1|^2$ with $E[|X_2|^2]>E[|X_1|^2]$ dose not mean that $|X_2|^2$ always greater the  $|X_1|^2$ and it  is possible that $|X_1|^2>|X_2|^2$?

Comment: Even  intuitively  $EX>EY$ only means $X>Y$ **on an average**. So it is highly unintuitive even to guess that $X>Y$ always.

Comment: I am just confusing. In some paper they say that we assume that $|X_1|^2<|X_2|^2$ and other they say $E[|X_2|^2]>E[|X_1|^2] $ so until now I do not know if they assume the same thing i.e, $E[|X_2|^2]>E[|X_1|^2] $ mean that $|X_1|^2<|X_2|^2$??

Comment: Can any one add more information it hold or not?